# What is a word that describes both "entry" and "exit"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you had to describe two locations, an "entry" and an "exit", what one word would encapsulate both meanings?  For example, I would describe them as "access locations".  But I want a single word that means that.

Comment: An entry and exit of what type? *Doorway*? *Gateway*? *Border*?

Comment: As @Jason Bassford points out, we are lacking in context. Do you want a formal word, informal? Please can you give a sample sentence that shows how you want to use the word?  You can leave a blank _____ where the word should be.

Comment: port, recess, opening, gate, portal, post etc.

Comment: @Marty I've added the correct tag. Please review the [tag info](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: As mentioned the word [**portal**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/portal) is quite wide in its scope. **Portals** can be physical doorways and general or virtual access points.

Comment: I am voting to close this question. It should include more details and clarify the problem. Are we to consider **all** locations - a pathway into the jungle and the point at which something is inserted or removed? (See also Jason Bassford's comment above.)

Comment: Maybe a crossing. Most doors, portals, gates, etc. can be closed, locked, barricaded, from one or both sides.

Comment: The request is probably computer related, a variable-whatzit  name

Comment: @Mari-Lou - In which case it could simply be *port*. However it's for the OP to tell us.

Comment: @chasly  The clue lies in the OP's suggestion “access locations” which sounds quite computery :)

Comment: I cast my vote to close because Marty has not provided further clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Access or Accessway

> **[accessway](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/accessway)**: a path, route, etc., that provides access to a specific destination or property, as to a public beach or state park

Answer (score 2):

How about **door**? From Lexico:

> **[door](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/door)**: A hinged, sliding, or revolving barrier at the entrance to a building, room, or vehicle, or in the framework of a cupboard

Doors are entrances to interior spaces and exits to exterior spaces. That is, they address both entry and exit, depending on one's direction of travel.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of buildings, @RichardKayser's suggestion of doors/doorways probably makes the most sense.

In more general circumstances, another word of use, defined via Merriam-Webster, is

> **[passageway](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passageway)**: a way that allows passage

Entrances and exits enable passage between spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If a more elegant term is required, perhaps:

> [**portal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portal)

which Merriam-Webster defines as:

“DOOR, ENTRANCE *especially : a grand or imposing one*”